# Can I recover a Skyrim saved game from a condemned computer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My computer is affected by a virus and so is Skyrim. Can I copy the saved game file, put it on a pendrive, and play Skyrim from the last saved point after formatting the whole computer?

Will this trick work or is the saved game file also affected by the virus?

Comment: are you using steam for skyrim?

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/site-scope-for-game-technical-questions)

Comment: Depends what virus. Some of them will encrypt all your data (e.g. cryptolocker and variants), making recovery impossible. The ones that don't, probably won't touch your game saves.

Comment: @Wouter i have steam on my computer but i generally don't use it to run skyrim.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can copy your save across to another machine/the same machine after reformatting.

However, if you've plugged a USB drive into an infected computer, chances are the drive itself could have been infected too.

I would *highly* recommend creating an [Antivirus LiveCD](http://livecdlist.com/purpose/windows-antivirus/), booting your computer from it and checking the USB drive and saved files, **before plugging the USB drive into anything else at all**.

You may find you can also repair/recover your computer using the LiveCD, however if you have any questions on that, you're probably better off asking on our sister site [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Noting that antiviruses (antivirii?) are typically imperfect, you should instead use a live environment to copy the save files off in the first place. It's better not to trust that an antivirus scan will actually detect anything.

Comment: @Bob can you please explain 'live environment'..??  thnx in advance.

Comment: @soham He means use the live cd OS to do the transfer off your virus infected machine.

Comment: @Soham For instance, booting on a Linux Live CD (thus not running on the infected OS) and retrieve your files (that are on the infected OS) from there.

Comment: To add a layer of security, transfering the saved game by email or using google drive is good too, as chances are low that the virus intercept the upload. :)

Comment: @LéonPelletier Not so good. One of the last things you want to do on an infected machine is enter credentials to your email...

Answer (score 0):

If you bought Skyrim on Steam then I think your save games and configuration are stored on Steam Cloud even though you did not start Skyrim from Steam. Steam detects if a game is running and sync it to the cloud when you close it.